# defining a value for a list in python

Tags: python

I am having a hive query which gets me store_front_id and count of failed records in below way

```
res = ['143460\t45', '143441\t477']
```

where the store front id is the first one followed by a tab separation and fail record count.
Now when I don't have any fail record count the value of "res" is empty.

I have store_front_list which has value like

```
store_front_list=['143460','143441']
```

and I am checking

```
if len(res) == 0:
```

Now i have to hard code the value like this

```
res = ['143460\t0', '143441\t0']
```

where it will read the store front ids from the store front list and append the 0 followed by a tab.
How do I do it.

Comment: Do what? You haven't described anything you want done.

Comment: I have to iterate thru store_front_list and get this result :res = ['143460\t0', '143441\t0']

Comment: When you say "get this result", do you mean you want to go through each element of the `store_front_list`, and add `\t0` to it?

Comment: `res = [i+'\t0' for i in store_front_list]`

Comment: Thanks I'll check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need your result to contain all store front IDs, regardless of whether their failure count is 0 or not. You can convert the `store_front_list` into a set, and remove the failed items from the set. The items that remain in the set are unfailed, and can be appended to `res` with a `\t0` attached:

```
def append_unfailed(res):
    unfailed = set(store_front_list)
    for r in res:
        store_front_id, failcnt = s.split('\t')
        unfailed.discard(store_front_id)
    for store_front_id in unfailed:
        res.append('%s\t0' % store_front_id)
```

Comment: The problem is, it might happen that one of the store_front_id returns result however, another is not. So in that case I'll have the value of res=['143460\t411'] so I'll have to check whether for every store front id the value is returned or not if not then I'll have to hard code it to zero.

Comment: @Debayan Your remark is very hard to follow. What does it mean that "one of the store_front_id returns result however, another is not"? The code in my answer is designed to yield the exact same result as if you hardcoded the `store_front_list` with `\t0` appended after every item. If this is insufficient, maybe you should clarify the requirements in the question.

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to say is : let say I have two store front ids 143460 and 143441 now I am having a hive query which fetches me the failed records for every store front id. Currently there is a scenario where both of the ids are not having any failed record. so I am not getting any output from hive query. But it might also happen that one of the store front id is having some failed record and other is not. I'll have to iterate thru the store_front_id_list check if it is having any failed record against it, if not then I shall have to hard code the value

Comment: so lets say currently res = = ['143460\t45', '143441\t477'] where 45 and 477 are the failed records respectively. Now If let say a scenario where there are no failed records the value of res = [] or may be failed records against one store_front_id then the value of res = ['143460\t45']. Now I have to iterate thru the store front id list and hard code the value 0 when there is no data against a store_front_id. so for first scenario the output should be res = ['143460\t0', '143441\t0'] and for the second case the output should be res = ['143460\t45', '143441\t0']

Comment: @Debayan I think I now understand what you're trying to do. Please see the edited answer.